# probability on the distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability

I'm trying to solve a variant of the BD problem

a) How many people have to be in a class so that there is a 50% chance that at least two people in the class have the same birthday?

Setup: 365*364*...365-n+1/(365***^n times) but stuck on the 50% incorporation

b) How many people have to be in the class so that there is a 50% chance of having the same birthday as the instructor?

Setup: I'm thinking to use complements but not sure

Answer (score 0):

HINT: for the first question (classical BP) you have to find the minimal value of $n $ so that $365! (365 - n)! /365^n \leq 0.5$.

For the second question, fixed the instructor's birthday, then the second, third, fourth... $n^{th}$ person  have all the same probability of not having the same birthday as the instructor.

Comment: I got n = 23, for the first one. For the second one I got 22. is that right?